# Paypal IPN and Shopping buttons

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn

I am currently using Paypal Shopping Buttons (Button Wizard) in my website. I need to use Paypal IPN to activate the software once a product has been purchased. 
Will IPN work if I use Paypal Shopping Buttons and set IPN Url in my profile settings page ?
Or should I use Website Payment Standards in order to use IPN ?

Thanks.

Comment: paypal will do an ipn if you set it in your profile but you would still need a way of checking the ipn is valid. there are some sample paypal ipn classes/code @ x.com like fabrik says

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by Website Payment Standards?

But regardless, Paypal gives you option to set any url for IPN. So, yes; you can set up url for your webiste, and from there on (url you snet IPN to) you do whatever needs to be done once user has made a payment